# Not able to edit Forecast category field in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, forecast

I am unable to edit the standard forecast category field in Salesforce 1. I am able to edit it through Salesforce UI; I tried through Salesforce1 simulator in chrome as well (Originally tried in my iPad) but still it showing as read only field...

Is there any additional settings required to be able to edit Forecast category in the Salesforce1

Answer (score 4):

This is currently not possible and there's an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l7KfAAI) and an [explanation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000192839&language=en_US) for it. What you are experiencing is not a bug but it's by "by design"